# Summing a nested list using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following Java POJOs:

```
public class Order {
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
    private String name;
    // ... lots of other fields

    // Getters & setters & ctors down here
}

public class OrderLine {
    private String productId;
    private Integer quantity;

    // Getters & setters & ctors down here
}
```

I'm trying to find a Java 8 "Streamy" way of grabbing the total quantity of all orderlines in an order. The "old" way of grabbing this count would look like this:

```
int totalQuantity = 0;
for (OrderLine ol : order.getOrderLines()) {
    totalQuantity += ol.getQuantity();  
}
```

My best attempt so far:

```
Integer totalQuantity = order.getOrderLines().stream().filter(ol -> ol.getQuantity());
```

I know this is wrong since its not iterating through the `List<OrderLine>` and summing each line's quantity, and it doesn't compile since `filter(...)` needs the expression to resolve to a `boolean`, not an `int` value.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`Stream.mapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), which creates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--). You can try this:

```
int totalQuantity = order.getOrderLines().stream()
        .mapToInt(OrderLine::getQuantity)
        .sum();
```

This will sum up the total quality of all order lines from an order.